# How to create a link to file in PhpDoc block or a comment in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

Is there a feature or a plugin to create a link to a local project file like this:

```
/**
 * @see ./views/templates/file.twig
 */
public function render()
{
  ..
}
```

That would very useful for jumping between files.

I've found this plugin, but is seems like it is no longer maintained or not supported in PhpStorm > 2016:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7235?pr=phpStorm

Comment: That plugin still works fine (works for me, at least)

Comment: This feature is not implemted yet. But you can vote up the feature request [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28196) and will hopefully be done soon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using fake functions in files:

```php
if (!function_exists('fakefunction___link')) { 
    function fakefunction___link() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then in another PHP file i have:

```php
/** @see fakefunction___link */
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

**PhpStorm 2023.2**:

```php
/**
 * @see /README.md  # It works
 * @see /.gitignore # It doesn't work (hidden files)
 */
class SomeClass
{
    // ...
}
```